# Create a NEW UITableViewCell from storyboard prototype

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Is it possible to create a NEW custom table view cell from a storyboard prototype?

The "normal" way is to dequeue a cell

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

but this is not what I need.

I tried to alloc a cell like this

```
CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

but this doesn't work. It creates an empty cell.

There is of course the possibility to do it programmatically, but that is not what I want, obviously.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Such question shows that you don't understand how cell reusing works. You shouldn't decide if you need to create new cell or not. `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should modify only specific values for a given cell.

Comment: what you want? use a custom cell?

Comment: @Szu I know how cell reusing works. The changes in the cells are very complex, so I cache cells. Anyway, I see now that this is not the solution for my problem. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "the changes to the cells are very complex" then you need multiple prototypes, not a single prototype which you keep changing.

Have a different reuse identifier for each one and determine which type you need before dequeuing.

Comment: You are right. Actually, it was a stupid question and wouldn't solve my problem even there is a solution I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSInteger isNewCell = 0;

//On adding UITableViewCell Add Action.
-(void) addCell
{
    [dataArray addObject:@""]; // dataArray should be the array that has the data for UITableViewCell of class NSMutableArray;
    isNewCell = 1;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if(isNewCell ==0)
    //your cell implementation
   else if(isNewCell ==1)
   {
        if(indexPath.row==[dataArray count])
            //new cell implementation
        else
           //other cell implementation
   }
}
```

I have posted the answer as far I understood your question. Comment @ answer what you expect more than this if my answer is not enough..

Comment: It not what I meant but thanks. I realized that the answer to my question doesn't solve my problem. :)